# When to use Sequelize and raw queries in mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to learn SQL database with Nodejs as I have worked only with NoSQL(Mongodb) with Nodejs. I have installed mysql database and gotten to a point where I can retrieve data from mysql database using Nodejs.

I was trying to setup a user auth using Nodejs, MySQL and possibly JWT. Most of the auth tutorials that I found online for this uses Sequelize. I have never used sequelize before.

Is it a good idea to use sequelize just for user authentication and then use mysql for other tasks? Is sequelize something that is going to be useful/recommended for other parts of my application where I have to pull data from my database?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Sequelize has been around for a long time - 2011. It has thousands of GitHub stars and is used by tons of applications. Due to it's age and popularity it is stable and has plenty of documentation available online.

In addition to it's maturity and stability, Sequelize has a large feature set that covers: queries, scopes, relations, transactions, raw queries, migrations, read replication, etc.

A thing to note is that Sequelize is promise-based, making it easier to manage asynchronous functions and exceptions. It also supports all the popular SQL dialects: PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite, and MSSQL.

On the other hand, there's no NoSQL support which can be seen in ORMs (or Object Document Mappers, in this case) such as Mongoose. Really, deciding which ORM to choose depends mainly on the requirements of the project you're working on.

Squelize will make use of sql databse very easy and smooth

you can know more about sequelize you can visit this intros and demos

1. [Optimism](https://milinaudara.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/an-introduction-to-sequelize-js/#:%7E:text=js%20%3F-,Sequelize.,to%20objects%20and%20vice%20versa.&text=It%20also%20provides%20database%20synchronization,by%20specifying%20the%20model%20structure.)
2. [Boilerplate](https://github.com/talyssonoc/node-api-boilerplate) of node.js and Sequelize
3. sequelize.org [docs](https://sequelize.org/v4/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html)